# Firebase - How do I read this map via embedded structs?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I am reading data from Firestore to be able to populate into expanding tableview cells. I have a really simple struct:

```
protocol PlanSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Plan{
    var menuItemName: String
    var menuItemQuantity: Int
    var menuItemPrice: Double

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "menuItemName": menuItemName,
            "menuItemQuantity": menuItemQuantity,
            "menuItemPrice": menuItemPrice
        ]
    }
}

extension Plan : PlanSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let menuItemName = dictionary["menuItemName"] as? String,
            let menuItemQuantity = dictionary["menuItemQuantity"] as? Int,
            let menuItemPrice = dictionary["menuItemPrice"] as? Double

        else { return nil }

        self.init(menuItemName: menuItemName, menuItemQuantity: menuItemQuantity, menuItemPrice: menuItemPrice)
    }
}
```

And this is embedded in this struct:

```
protocol ComplainSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Complain{
    var status: Bool
    var header: String
    var message: String
    var timeStamp: Timestamp
    var email: String
    var planDetails: Plan

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "status": status,
            "E-mail": header,
            "Message": message,
            "Time_Stamp": timeStamp,
            "User_Email": email,
            "planDetails": planDetails
        ]
    }
}

extension Complain : ComplainSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let status = dictionary["status"] as? Bool,
            let header = dictionary["E-mail"] as? String,
            let message = dictionary["Message"] as? String,
            let timeStamp = dictionary["Time_Stamp"] as? Timestamp,
            let email = dictionary["User_Email"] as? String,
            let planDetails = dictionary["planDetails"] as? Plan

        else { return nil }

        self.init(status: status, header: header, message: message, timeStamp: timeStamp, email: email, planDetails: planDetails)
    }
}
```

However, I am not able to query any data from Firestore which looks like this:
[image]

Here is my query, although I am just reading all the files:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var messageArray = [Complain]()

func loadMenu() {
        db.collection("Feedback_Message").getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.messageArray = documentSnapshot!.documents.compactMap({Complain(dictionary: $0.data())})
                for plan in self.messageArray {
                    print("\(plan.email)")
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.testTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?
**EDIT**:
As suggested, here is the updated embedded struct:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Complain
struct Complain: Codable {
    let eMail, message, timeStamp, userEmail: String
    let status: Bool
    let planDetails: PlanDetails

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case eMail = "E-mail"
        case message = "Message"
        case timeStamp = "Time_Stamp"
        case userEmail = "User_Email"
        case status, planDetails
    }
}

// MARK: - PlanDetails
struct PlanDetails: Codable {
    let menuItemName: String
    let menuItemQuantity: Int
    let menuItemPrice: Double
}
```

Comment: Look at using https://quicktype.io/ . Will generate the structs for you. Further more, you do not loop over Plan Details, nor access its first element hence the empty response.

Comment: How would I loop through the map if I am applying the dictionary to the entire snapshot? Do I have to now loop through each document in the snapshot and within each loop, loop through all of the maps?

Comment: Have a look at quicktype.io and let me know how you go? Using Decodables will remove a lot of the headaches you have.

Comment: I updated the struct as suggested. Since there is no dictionary, I will have to loop through the snapshot (which is fine) but then how do I loop through the maps (which I am completely confused by).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60955542/how-do-i-loop-through-a-firestore-document-that-has-an-array-of-maps/60955930#60955930

Answer (score 1):

Using quicktype.io, you can generate the struct. From there, all you need to do is run this tiny fragment of code within your response handler.

```
    var compainArray = [Complain]()
func loadMenu() {
    db.collection("Feedback_Message").getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            guard let snapshot = documentSnapshot else {return}

            for document in snapshot.documents {
                if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: document.data()){
                    if let converted = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Complain.self, from: jsonData){
                        self.compainArray.append(converted)
                    }
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.testTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will handle the looping, and mapping of certain variables. Let me know if you have any trouble with this.

Comment: I generated the struct (its at the bottom of the original post). I get an error in AppDelegate: "Invalid type in JSON write (FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot)". I am not sure at this point if something is wrong with the struct or the response handler.

Comment: @BVB09 I have updated to code, sorry for not being clear before.

Comment: No need to use JSON serialization to get data from a Firestore snapshot. The snapshot property is a `QuerySnapshot` and the documents property is an array of `FIRDocumentSnapshot`. All you need to do is iterate the array and use the built-in `get()` method made specifically to avoid the use of JSON serialization. I answered this exact question for OP the other day but it looks like he's back to old habits.

Comment: Hi bsod, sorry you did provid the right answer in the other thread. I should have clarified that the struct in itself does not create an array of the map within the main array which I use to populate the table.