# How do I loop through a firestore document that has an array of maps?

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I mostly work with dictionaries since I am fairly new but here we have an embedded struct that I need to loop through. With this, I need to be able to populate expanding cells in UITableView.

My struct looks like this:

```
struct Complain: Codable {
    let eMail, message, timeStamp, userEmail: String
    let status: Bool
    let planDetails: PlanDetails

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case eMail = "E-mail"
        case message = "Message"
        case timeStamp = "Time_Stamp"
        case userEmail = "User_Email"
        case status, planDetails
    }
}

// MARK: - PlanDetails
struct PlanDetails: Codable {
    let menuItemName: String
    let menuItemQuantity: Int
    let menuItemPrice: Double
}
```

And my query looks like this:

```
db.collection("Feedback_Message").getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                for document in documentSnapshot!.documents {
                    let eMail = document.get("E-mail")
                    let message = document.get("Message")
                    let timeStamp = document.get("Time_Stamp")
                    let userEmail = document.get("User_Email")
                    let planDetails = document.get("planDetails")

                    // how to loop through planDetails
            }
        }
```

[image]

I have gotten this far:

```
db.collection("Feedback_Message").getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
            if let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot {
                for document in documentSnapshot.documents {
                    guard let planDetails = document.get("planDetails") as? [[String : Any]] else {
                        let email = document.get("E-mail")
                        let message = document.get("Message")
                        let timeStamp = document.get("Time_Stamp")
                        let userEmail = document.get("User_Email")
                        let status = false
                    }
                    for plan in planDetails {
                        if let menuItemName = plan["menuItemName"] as? String {
                            // not sure I populate the menuItemsName, menuItemsQuantity and menuItemsPrice within the array
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE 2:
[image]

**Final query:** This is finally working as expected. But am not able to populate the expanding cells.

```
db.collection("Feedback_Message").getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
            if let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot {
                for document in documentSnapshot.documents {
                    guard let planDetails = document.get("planDetails") as? [[String : Any]],
                        let email = document.get("E-mail") as? String,
                        let message = document.get("Message") as? String,
                        let timeStamp = document.get("Time_Stamp") as? String,
                        let userEmail = document.get("User_Email") as? String,
                        let status = document.get("status") as? Bool else {
                            continue
                        }
                    for plan in planDetails {
                        guard let menuItemName = plan["menuItemName"] as? String,
                            let menuItemQuantity = plan["menuItemQuantity"] as? Int,
                            let menuItemPrice = plan["menuItemPrice"] as? Double else {
                                continue
                        }
                        let planDetails = PlanDetails(menuItemName: menuItemName, menuItemQuantity: menuItemQuantity, menuItemPrice: menuItemPrice)
                        let complaint = Complain(eMail: email, message: message, timeStamp: timeStamp, userEmail: userEmail, status: status, planDetails: planDetails)
                        self.messageArray.append(complaint)
                        print(self.messageArray)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
// OPTION 1 - FULL REQUIREMENT
db.collection("Feedback_Message").getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
    if let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot {
        for document in documentSnapshot.documents {
            // all of these properties are required to parse a single document
            guard let planDetails = document.get("planDetails") as? [[String : Any]],
                let email = document.get("E-mail") as? String,
                let message = document.get("Message") as? String,
                let timeStamp = document.get("Time_Stamp") as? String,
                let userEmail = document.get("User_Email") as? String,
                let status = document.get("status") as? Bool else {
                    continue // continue this loop
            }
            for plan in planDetails {
                // all of these properties are required to instantiate a struct
                guard let name = plan["menuItemName"] as? String,
                    let price = plan["menuItemName"] as? Double,
                    let quantity = plan["menuItemQuantity"] as? Int else {
                        continue // continue this loop
                }
                let plan = PlanDetails(menuItemName: name, menuItemQuantity: quantity, menuItemPrice: price)
                // then you will likely append this plan to an array 
            }
        }
    }
}

// OPTION 2 - PARTIAL REQUIREMENT
db.collection("Feedback_Message").getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
    if let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot {
        for document in documentSnapshot.documents {
            // all of these properties are required to parse a single document
            guard let planDetails = document.get("planDetails") as? [[String : Any]],
                let email = document.get("E-mail") as? String,
                let message = document.get("Message") as? String else {
                    continue // continue this loop
            }
            // these properties are not required
            let timeStamp = document.get("Time_Stamp") as? String // optional (can be nil)
            let userEmail = document.get("User_Email") as? String // optional (can be nil)
            let status = document.get("status") as? Bool ?? false // not optional because it has a default value of false
            for plan in planDetails {
                // all of these properties are required to instantiate a struct
                guard let name = plan["menuItemName"] as? String,
                    let price = plan["menuItemName"] as? Double,
                    let quantity = plan["menuItemQuantity"] as? Int else {
                        continue // continue this loop
                }
                let plan = PlanDetails(menuItemName: name, menuItemQuantity: quantity, menuItemPrice: price)
                // then you will likely append this plan to an array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are a number of other ways you can do this, these are just a couple. For example, you can instantiate the struct with the `[String: Any]` dictionary itself.

Comment: Hi - sorry my newbienes is realy showing here; I sort of get you and have updated my code at the bottom of the original post. I have a messageArray which contains struct type Complaint but I am not sure how to go about populating the embedded part of each struct and looping to repeat.

Comment: @BVB09 Everyone's newbiness is showing somewhere. I edited my answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks. I learnt quite a bit. However, I am not able to populate the expanding cells in the TableView. I posted a screenshot of the 2 errors. I am not sure what I am doing wrong there.

Comment: How do you want to populate the table? The `messageArray` is an array of `Complaint`. Should each row in the table represent a complaint or should each complaint represent a section and within each section what are the rows?

Comment: The number of sections will be the total number of complaints at the start i.e. messageArray.count. When the user taps on the complaint section then the corresponding rows of planDetails will open up underneath. I found this video to indicate what I am trying to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClrSpJ3txAs&t=650s. So each section (at the top) will be a complaint and the rows underneath it should be details with the menuItems, menuItemPrice and menuItemQuantity.

Comment: P.S. I have not created the entire cell, just want to test the expanding functionality and ensure that the rows and sections are being populated accordingly.

Comment: Then for the number of rows within the section, just return `3`. If that number is dynamic based on the plan details, then you can create a property in the struct that keeps a counter for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was. Had to do with the way I setup the struct and how I populate the array.

Right way is as such i.e. the planDetails need to be cast as an array:

```
struct Complain: Codable {
    let eMail, message, timeStamp, userEmail: String
    let status: Bool
    let planDetails: [PlanDetails]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case eMail = "E-mail"
        case message = "Message"
        case timeStamp = "Time_Stamp"
        case userEmail = "User_Email"
        case status, planDetails
    }
}

// MARK: - PlanDetails
struct PlanDetails: Codable {
    let menuItemName: String
    let menuItemQuantity: Int
    let menuItemPrice: Double
}
```

And then I need to iterate through each plan item, add it to the array and then add the array to the top level Complain:

```
db.collection("Feedback_Message").getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
            if let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot {
                for document in documentSnapshot.documents {
                    guard let planDetails = document.get("planDetails") as? [[String : Any]],
                        let email = document.get("E-mail") as? String,
                        let status = document.get("status") as? Bool else {
                            continue
                        }

                    for plan in planDetails {
                        guard let menuItemName = plan["menuItemName"] as? String,
                        let menuItemQuantity = plan["menuItemQuantity"] as? Int else {
                                continue
                        }
                        let singlePlan = PlanDetails(menuItemName: menuItemName, menuItemQuantity: menuItemQuantity)
                        self.planDetailsArray.append(singlePlan)
                    }
                    let complain = Complain(eMail: email, status: status, planDetails: self.planDetailsArray)
                    self.planDetailsArray.removeAll()
                    self.messageArray.append(complain)
                }
            }
            // Print the main array or load table
            }
        }
```

bsod's answer stays as the correct answer because without his help, I would not have been able to arrive at his conclusion.